# How to give everyone sudo permission on all nodes in HPC cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, sudo, hpc, sudoers

I have a 100 node CentOS 7.5 HPC cluster and I want to give everyone permission to run a script owned by root on all nodes, /usr/sbin/dropcaches.sh

Logging into all 100 nodes and doing visudo would be extremely painful and prone to mistakes.

Is it possible to create a file in /etc/sudoers.d on the head node and just cp it to every node in the cluster that gives everyone permission to execute /usr/sbin/dropcaches.sh please?

Many thanks
M

Comment: *How to give everyone sudo permission on all nodes in HPC cluster*  This will end in tears.

Comment: not for everything... just to drop caches, i.e. so they can clear the cache before they start running their jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my question.

I am using Centos 7.5 and you can just add a file in /etc/sudoers.d with the command in it that you want.

So for me I wanted everyone to be able to drop_caches before running their HPC job:

I created a file called /etc/sudoers.d/dropcaches which looked like:

```
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/dropcaches.sh
```

and the contents of /usr/sbin/drop_caches.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

So now everyone is able to issue

> sudo dropcaches

on each node in the cluster that they wanted to use